# Spock testing : cleaning after "where:" block finishes

Tags: groovy, spock

I have 2 test methods .

They all execute each line of the where block, I need a cleanup for add & relax methods.

I've tried cleanup block ,   void cleanup()  , def cleanupSpec() , non suits .

How can I explicitly run a cleanup after specific method which have "where:" block?

```
def "Add"() {
   setup :
   expect : 
   where:
    }

def "Relax"() {
   setup :
   expect : 
   where:     
    }
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear. Could you please provide an example?

Comment: never mind , i just put a new method between 'add' and 'relax' , called it 'addClean' , and reset everything from there.

Comment: my cleanup method ->  def "Add cleanup - not a test"() {
        expect:
            !cache.clear()
    }

Comment: I stumbled onto this question and noticed that the question is a bit unclear, and to be honest so is your solution in the comment above. Could you either rephrase the question to make it more clear what you're asking, provide an answer to the question with your working solution and mark it correct, or should this question be deleted/closed alltogether?

Answer (score 17):

You can have a cleanup block in your method like so:

```
@Unroll
def "a method that tests stuff"(){
  given: 
    def foo = fooDAO.save(new Foo(name: name))
  when: 
    def returned = fooDAO.get(foo.id)
  then:
    returned.properties == foo.properties
  cleanup:
    fooDAO.delete(foo.id)
  where:
    name << ['one', 'two']
}
```

The "cleanup" block will get run once per test iteration.

Comment: As i wrote, i tried it, and i need a cleanup once at the end of all the iterations.

Comment: It is possible that you may need to @Unroll your method in order for it to cleanup after each iteration.

Answer (score 5):

If you use `@Unroll`, then `cleanup:` will be called for every entry in the `where:` block. To only run cleanup **once** then move your code inside the `def cleanupSpec()` closure.

```
@Shared
def arrayOfIds = []

@Unroll
def "a method that tests stuff"(){
  given: 
  def foo = fooDAO.save(new Foo(name: name))
when: 
  def returned = fooDAO.get(foo.id)
  arrayOfIds << foo.id
then:
  returned.properties == foo.properties
where:
  name << ['one', 'two']
}

def cleanupSpec() {
  arrayOfIds.each {
     fooDAO.delete(it)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, but note that it requires moving the test to its own class file; otherwise the `cleanupSpec` will wait for _all_ tests to complete, potentially with polluted data.

Answer (score 0):

`cleanupSpec()` is unusable because it is called after **all** tests of spec, not after last "where" item.

If your spec will contain more than one test, database will remain poisoned with stuff from "a method that tests stuff" until all tests in this file will finish.